# interpolate animation value in flutter

Tags: flutter, animation, math, dart

If I want to convert a range from 0.0 to 1.0, into a range from 20.0 to 80.0, I can use `lerpDouble(20.0, 80.0, animationValue)`.

How do I convert a range from 0.8 to 1.0, into a range from 0.0 to 1.0?

Comment: where does the 5 come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging I found a simple solution to the problem:

```
final value = Interval(0.8, 1.0).transform(animationValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Dear you can use this plugging to animation  in a flutter   [Here Link](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_interpolation)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
(lerpDouble(0.8, 1.0, animationValue) * 1.0/0.2) - 4.0
```

When:

- animationValue=0.8 => (0.8*5)-4.0 = 0.0
- animationValue=1.0 => (1.0*5)-4.0 = 1.0

This is to do the other way round:

```
0.8 + 0.2 * lerpDouble(0.0, 1.0, animationValue)
```

When:

- animationValue=0.0 => 0.8+(0.2*0) = 0.8
- animationValue=1.0 => 0.8+(0.2*1) = 1.0

Comment: could you elaborate where the values come from?

Comment: Hello @LeonardoSilva details depend on your code but this formula will do: when animationValue is 0.0 then 0.8+0.2*0=0.8 and when animationValue is 1.0 then 0.8+0.2*1=1.0; so you will have values between 0.8 and 1.0

Comment: (lerpDouble(0.8, 1.0, animationValue) * 1.0/0.2) - 4 @LeonardoSilva